# Fixed logo in pdf

Tags: pdf, scroll

I want a logo on the right corner of a pdf file.
It needs to be clickable and has to stay fixed so if the reader scrolls down its has to stay on the same place so the logo stays in the screen.

Someone knows how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible with PDF pages. Any visible content belongs to a page so when the page scrolls, all the page related content scrolls.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is impossible in PDF. But, you can do that with jQuery on website.

Comment: Yea i know it works on website's but i am realy looking how i can do it in PDF's

Comment: You can't do it in PDF,because PDF is book-format and PDF don't support any animations like that...